# php parse file not sure what format

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I have an piece of hardware that returns temperature data etc. I am not sure what format this is though. I would like to parse it with php any suggestions on the best or easiest way to parse the data. I will be storing the data in a mysql database and this data will be inserted one every 30 seconds.

Below is the data:

`{name:"Enviro",date:"07/22/10 17:32:34",uptime:"0d 19:06:28",scale:0,macaddr:"00:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX",devtype:"24",refresh:"30",sensor:[{label:"Rack Temp",tempf:"70.88",tempc:"21.60",highf:"72.50",highc:"22.50",lowf:"69.98",lowc:"21.10",alarm:1,type:38,enabled:1,humid:"37.27",highh:"45.72",lowh:"34.01",heati:"76.79",heatic:"24.88",highhi:"77.07",highhic:"25.03",lowhi:"76.57",lowhic:"24.76",hienabled:0},{label:"Ext. Sensor 1",tempf:"32.00",tempc:"0.00",highf:"32.00",highc:"0.00",lowf:"32.00",lowc:"0.00",alarm:0,type:0,enabled:0},{label:"HVAC",tempf:"46.27",tempc:"7.93",highf:"67.87",highc:"19.93",lowf:"43.70",lowc:"6.50",alarm:1,type:16,enabled:1},{label:"Ext. Sensor 3",tempf:"32.00",tempc:"0.00",highf:"32.00",highc:"0.00",lowf:"32.00",lowc:"0.00",alarm:0,type:0,enabled:0},{label:"Ext. Sensor 4",tempf:"32.00",tempc:"0.00",highf:"32.00",highc:"0.00",lowf:"32.00",lowc:"0.00",alarm:0,type:0,enabled:0},{label:"Ext. Sensor 5",tempf:"32.00",tempc:"0.00",highf:"32.00",highc:"0.00",lowf:"32.00",lowc:"0.00",alarm:0,type:0,enabled:0},{label:"Ext. Sensor 6",tempf:"32.00",tempc:"0.00",highf:"32.00",highc:"0.00",lowf:"32.00",lowc:"0.00",alarm:0,type:0,enabled:0}],switch_sen:[{label:"Air Flow",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0},{label:" ",enabled:1,alarm:1,status:0}]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get it in an array:

```
$str = '...';
$arr = json_decode(preg_replace('/([{,])([^:{,]+):/', '${1}"${2}":', $str));
var_dump($arr);
```

Simple/Perfect/Best ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It think it is in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.

Comment: Strictly speaking, JSON would require the names in the name/value pairs to be quoted, ie `"label"` rather than `label`. See the [json_decode()](http://us3.php.net/json-decode) docs, Example #3. My PHP 5.3.3 cannot parse your string.

Comment: It's not JSON since the keys to the objects are not quoted.  It's very similar though (in fact, it looks like pure JS objects)...  Perhaps it's time to build a JS object parser?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it using [PEAR package - Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON)